# Model non-deterministic value integer in Frama-C

Tags: frama-c

Could anyone please tell me is this the right model for non-deterministic values of integer and unsigned integer in Frama-C?

```html
/* Suppose Frama-C is installed in /usr/local -default prefix */
#include "/usr/local/share/frama-c/builtin.h"
#include "/usr/local/share/frama-c/libc/limits.h"

...
#define nondet_int() Frama_C_interval(INT_MIN, INT_MAX)
#define nondet_uint() Frama_C_interval(0, UINT_MAX)
...
```

Are there any exceptions if I use the above code with different architectures in option `-machdep`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason `Frama_C_interval(0, UINT_MAX)` may not work as intended is that `Frama_C_interval` has type `int (int, int)`. When you happen to want the entire range of `unsigned int` values, that actually tends to help because the conversions that are introduced are subject to approximation, but in general the fact that `Frama_C_interval` is declared as returning an `int` is a nuisance.

The latest released version already has `Frama_C_unsigned_int_interval`, but it is in `share/libc/__fc_builtin.h` (installed to `/usr/local/share/frama-c/libc/__fc_builtin.h`. The file `builtin.h` looks like a vestigial remnant, especially with the $Id$ line dating back to when development was done under SVN.

For specifying that a value should be all possible `unsigned int`values, `Frama_C_unsigned_int_interval(0, -1)` saves yourself the trouble of including `limit.h`. The `int` value `-1` passed as argument is converted to the largest `unsigned int` as per C rules.

Answer (score 3):

No, in the Neon version you have to manually define the appropriate macro if you want to use another `-machdep`. You would typically end up with a command-line like that:

```
frama-c -cpp-extra-args="-D__FC_MACHDEP_X86_64" -machdep x86_64
```

Forthcoming Sodium release will make the `-cpp-extra-args` unnecessary, as well as providing by default a `-I` option to let preprocessor search into Frama-C's `libc` header, so that you won't have to provide it yourself or rely on absolute paths in your `#include` directive

**NB:** This answer is not a commitment to any particular date for the Sodium release.